How the TRIM function works in this example?
I don't understand why the asterisk won't be placed after 92 and 110, if the TRIM function is excluded or the TRIM function is moved outside of the || function.
The DBP_CHK OUTPUT in the SAS LOG before being applied the concatenation on
DATA EXAMPLE8;
      INPUT SBP DBP @@;
      LENGTH SBP_CHK DBP_CHK $ 4;
      SBP_CHK = PUT(SBP,3.);
      DBP_CHK = PUT(DBP,3.);
      LDBP_CHK = LENGTHC(DBP_CHK);
      IF SBP GT 160 THEN SBP_CHK = SUBSTR(SBP_CHK,1,3) || '*'; 
      IF DBP GT 90 THEN DBP_CHK = TRIM(DBP_CHK) || '*'; 
      put DBP_CHK $quote.;
      DATALINES;
      120 80 180 92 200 110
      ;
      PROC PRINT DATA=EXAMPLE8 NOOBS;
      TITLE "Listing of Example 8";
      RUN;

If I do DBP_CHK = TRIM(DBP_CHK); before the IF-THEN statement, and then just have DBP_CHK = DBP_CHK|| '*', it won't work out.


In SAS DATA Step the value of a character variable is padded with spaces to the length of the variable.
Suppose you have code:
LENGTH DBP_CHK $ 4;
DBP_CHK = '1' ;
DBP_CHK = DBP_CHK || '*';

The concatendated result is $5 ( 1       * ) that is forced into a $4 container (DBP_CHK) and thus truncation of the result occurs, and you scratch your head.

I check the value of DBP_CHK in the SAS log by using put DBP_CHK $quote.;. It shows (
one leading black then  92 ). How does the TRIM function apply in this case when TRIM only removes trailing blanks?

Use $HEX40. as a debug aid to see exactly what character is there.  It could be a non-printable character that looks like a space in the output.  Common culprits are tab (09x), newline(0ax), carriage return (0dx), or hardspace (a0x).

STRIP() will remove leading and trailing blanks.  Before there was STRIP(), you would use TRIM(LEFT()).  But probably better to use the CATS function, e.g.  CATS(DBP_CHK,'*')  because that will strip and concatenate.

Can you explain more details about the $HEX40.  , I got the outputs in the SAS LOG as   20383020    20393220  31313020 .  Besides, If I placed the code as  DBP_CHK = TRIM(DBP_CHK);  IF DBP GT 90 THEN DBP_CHK = DBP_CHK || *; There are no asterisks either. Why is that?

If you do DBP_CHK = TRIM(DBP_CHK);  there will be no difference to the value of DBP_CHK.  The TRIM function will trim trailing blanks, but when the trimmed value is written to the variable, it will be padded with blanks again.  Because every character value in a SAS dataset is padded with blanks if the length of the value is less than the length of the variable.  SAS has fixed-length variables.

I under that part. Then as for the DBP_CHK, before we apply the concatenation, how does the value '92' look like? Is it 92 with 2 trailing blanks? In the SAS log, it shows as a leading black then 92.

The PUT(numeric-expression, numeric-format) function will right-align the output, thus introducing a leading space.  I would recommend using CATS(numeric-expression) function which implicitly uses BEST. format and strips the result for you.

Yes. But I want to understand how the TRIM function works out for this situation since now there are leading spaces for these values. TRIM can only remove trailing blanks.

In your example I see one leading blank, so the value is ' 92'.  Using TRIM on that value will have no effect, as you say it will not effect the leading blank.  If you want to avoid that leading blank you would change the PUT function to left align the value: DBP_CHK = PUT(DBP,3. -l);   Adding -l will left align the value when the length of the value is less than 3, instead of adding the leading blank(s).

So how the code DBP_CHK = TRIM(DBP_CHK) || '*';  can successfully add the * to the end, while DBP_CHK = DBP_CHK || '*';  cannot?

Based on your comments, the value after the put will be space-9-2-space.  Notice the trailing space because the variable is $4, and the put used format 3.

SAS character variables have a fixed length and are padded on the right with blanks.  Any time you do: x=x||'*'; it will not work, because the the value of x always uses the full length of the variable x.  So there is no room to add a character to it.

After the put statement, the value for 92 is shown as  blank 92. Do you mean that when it is delivered to the concatenate function, it is padded as  blank 92   blank and therefore the TRIM function can remove that trailing blank and make it 3 bytes, then we can concatenate the asterisk?

The variable DBP_CHK has  a length of $4.  The statement DBP_CHK = PUT(DBP,3.); will assign DBP_CHK the value 'blank'92'blank'.  The blank at the end is added because the value must be four characters long, because the length of the variable is 4.  Yes, TRIM can remove the trailing blank, and the so the value is now 'blank'92, and then there is room to add the asterisk as the fourth character.
